# Elasticsearch exact match pharse

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search a pharse in Elasticsearch for exact match. But Elasticsearch giving other containing pharses too.

An example; I want to search for "little cat", but Elasticsearch returns "little cat jump", "little cats", "little cat saved the baby from death", etc...

I just want exact and only "little cat", not the others. How can I do this query?

My contents like;

```
{
    title: "little cat",
    content: "bla bla bla"
},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on how `title` is indexed. For such a requirement, `title` would need to be [analyzed as `keyword`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), meaning whatever text is in `title` exactly like that is put in ES' internal Lucene inverted index.

And a `term` filter would be the choice for searching `little cat` in `title` analyzed as `keyword`.

If you want to have other operations made to your `title` field at indexing time, you can [add a filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html), for example for lowercasing any upper-case letters. But, in any case, you DO need a `keyword` analyzer.

If you don't want to change how `title` is being indexed now, you can [make it as `multi_field`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) and add a `title_keyword` (for example) field that should be indexed using your `keyword` analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

When indexing string fields, default mapping index type for strings is `analyzed` (like a full text index on `MySQL`). You should recreate the mapping and set index type to `not_analyzed`.

Look this for more about [Core Types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) and
[mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)